# Google WebToolkit + Google App Engine: is it really for free?

Tags: google-apps

I'm considering to use google web toolkit to develop my web application. It is not clear if the service is completely free for web storage under 500 mb.

Can I use google web toolkit to develop my own app, and use my own server for it ? Am I going to have some issues if I do this ?

Could you give me some feedback ?
Thanks

Comment: this question is offtopic on Super User.  it may be suitable for our sister site, Stack Overflow (though the SO community may decide to close it there).  good luck with your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GWT by itself and support it on your own server.  I'm not too familiar with google app engine, but from the website, it says:

> "Risk free trial period Not only is
>   creating an App Engine application
>   easy, it's free! You can create an
>   account and publish an application
>   that people can use right away at no
>   charge, and with no obligation. An
>   efficient application on a free
>   account can use up to 1GB of storage
>   and up to 5 million page views a
>   month. When you are ready for more,
>   you can enable billing, set a maximum
>   daily budget, and allocate your budget
>   for each resource according to your
>   needs."

It sounds like it is free for as along as you stay below the above quotas.

Comment: I agree with you, if you stay below the quotas it is completely free, but then why they write the word "period" ? Risk free trial period ? Probably is my english language limitation. Could you tell me what that mean ? thanks!

Comment: one more thing: is this an alternative framework I can use on my server instead of using google servers ? Just curious... http://appscale.cs.ucsb.edu/

Comment: The language in that sentence is just informal.  "Period" really offers no functional benefit to the sentence.  They are essentially saying there are no exceptions to this "risk free trial"

Comment: GWT compiles to HTML and javascript files. If you use java servlets in your application, then you will need a server that supports that functionality.  See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying.html  The link gives a general idea of what you need to do to deploy yourself versus using google app engine. It looks like the link you provided is trying to accomplish the exact same thing that google app engine is accomplishing.